# C++ conditional operator with void operand(s)

Tags: c++, void, conditional-operator

I’m trying to understand the following excerpt from the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003, newer versions say essentially the same):

> 5.16 Conditional operator
>
> 2 If either the second or the third operand has type (possibly cv-qualified) void, then the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the second
>   and third operands, ...

I am inclined to thinking that in this context, when an operand is a function call, then the type of the operand is taken to be (although it is not) the function return type. If that is so, then that yields an example of a void type.

I also imagine that a throw expression could also be surmised to have type void in this context, independently of the type of the throw operand. That would then be another example.

Are my two assumptions right? Are there any other cases?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

About throw, yes, there is no result, so the type is void and the type of the throw operand is irrelevant. I'm not sure how it could be relevant so that question seems odd.

About functions, I don't know why you say the type of the operand is not the function return type if the operand is a function call. What else would it be? It's where the operand is a function (as opposed to a function call) that function-to-pointer conversion would kick in.

The result type of the conditional operator depends on the type of it's operands. 
I think the special language around one of the operands being void is simply that the result of the conditional operator is then void, so the rules about possibly performing conversions of operands of different types are not relevant.

Comment: I said that because the type of a function is constructed out of the parameters it takes, its return value, and any cv qualifiers (8.3.5 Functions). So the type of a function pointer adds the ‘pointer’ qualification to that. If only the return would be taken into consideration then two pointers to functions which take different parameters and return the same type would be of the same type. Disaster. But it appears that, in the context of this operator, just the fact that the function returns void or not is all it matters (I mean, in the paragraph I quoted)